# Using variables for operator/methods

Tags: ruby, datamapper

How do you access an operator/method via a variable?

So instead of this:

```
c = Computer.new
c.computer_name = "bla"
c.operating_system = "Windows XP"
c.user_name = "joesmith"
c.save
```

(plus many more)

I want to use a hash and assign the values dynamically:

```
c = Computer.new
params.each do |key,val|
    c."#{key}" = val.to_s
end
c.save
```

Also, what is the correct terminology here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One trivial way (not DataMapper-specific, but assumes a `prop_name=` method), is to use `send`:

```
c.send("#{key}=".to_sym, val.to_s)
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try it, but `Computer.new params` should work.
Be careful of [mass assignment](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment) though (it's not specific to DataMapper).

Comment: +1, somehow I forgot DM has the normal AR-style init-from-hash.